# Trouble using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have made an array filled with randomized ints. Im trying to find out the biggest & smalest elements in it by using pointers in two different functions.

But one of my problem is that when I compare to find the lowest element the first element in my array changes to the found min-value.

```
        // Compare to find min value

        min = array;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (*min > *(min + i))
                *min = *(min + i);
        }

        // show array using pointer

        ptr = resetArray;      // Fill int *ptr with original array

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << *(ptr + i) << std::endl;
        }
```

After this comparment is done it moves the *min value to the begining of the array replacing the first element in it.

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: You change it yourself with `*min = *(min + i)`.

Comment: That is exactly what `*min = *(min + i);` does. What did you intend?

Comment: That is what happens if you use pointers.  If you do not want to modify the array you need a stand alone variable to store the min in.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I see it now! Sorry! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have a misconception about how pointers work (or maybe it's a simple mistake).

A pointer such as `int*` is not a variable for keeping track of an `int`. An `int*` pointer allows you to access some *other* variable that keeps track of an `int`. The pointer "points" at some other memory location; that is what they are for.

In your case, `min` is pointing to the integer in the array. `min` is not some separate storage for an integer. The fact that `array[i] == *min` is not merely because they happen to have equivalent integers; even more than that, **they are pointing to the same memory location**. If you change one, you change the other since they are the same memory location.

What you probably want to do instead, assuming you want to keep your current loop&pointer style you have, is to have a separate pointer for iterating over the array and set `min` (not `*min`) equal to the iterating pointer. That is:

```
int* iterator;
for(...)
    if(*iterator < *min)
        min = iterator
    iterator += 1;
```

Personally, I would just access the array with `array[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You let the pointer *min* point to the first value of the array, hence this value gets overwritten. Instead you should declare *min* as of the  non-pointer type that *array* elements are of, e.g.:

```
    auto min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (min > array[i])
            min = array[i];
    }
```

In any case, since you use c++, you might consider using the function [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).